# Unable to assign the result returned by the Method that receives a generic List and returns a List<?>

Tags: java, list, generics, java-stream, unbounded-wildcard

I'm trying to filter a List of objects that implements an interface. And I'm trying to create a generic method for all the classes.

Something like:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    String getFlag();
}


class SomeObject implements SomeInterface {
    public String getFlag() {
        return "X";
    }
}


List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

// Compilation error here
List<SomeObject> filterList = filterGenericList(someObjectList, "X");


private List<?> filterGenericList(List<? extends SomeInterface> objects, String flag) {
        return objects.stream()
                .filter(it -> it.getFlag().equals(flag))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How do I run away from the compilation Error?

```
 Incompatible types. 
 Found: 'java.util.List<capture<?>>', 
 Required: 'java.util.List<SomeObject>'
```

Comment: Why do you expect the result of `filterGenericList` to be a `List<SomeObject>`?  Your method doesn't say that, it says it returns a list of _anything_.

Comment: I know that. I'm trying to get a way to return a list of my object, using the interface to not create a lot of methods (one per class that implements the interface)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you return `List<?>` that means the method returns a list of some unknown type. Java doesn't know that it's the same type of list as the input list. To signal that, create a generic type `T` and have both the input and output lists be `List<T>`.

```
private <T extends SomeInterface> List<T> filterGenericList(List<T> objects, String flag) {
    return objects.stream()
        .filter(it -> it.getFlag().equals(flag))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Unbounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) `<?>` also called the *unknown type* is a way to tell the compiler that a generic type can't be predicted, and therefore the compiler will disallow to assign a list of *unknown type* to a list of `SomeObject` because it's impossible to ensure that this assignment is safe.

If you have a list of objects that belong to different classes implementing `SomeInterface` in order to distinguish between them, you can explicitly pass an instance of target class `Class<T>` into a method as an argument.

Seems like you're trying to reinvent the same mechanism by utilizing method `getFlag()`. It doesn't look reliable because nothing can stop you from making a typo or accidentally implementing `getFlag()` in two different classes in such a way that it'll return the same value.

```
private <T extends SomeInterface> List<T> filterGenericList(List<? extends SomeInterface> objects, 
                                                            Class<T> targetClass) {
    return objects.stream()
        .filter(it -> targetClass.isAssignableFrom(it.getClass()))
        .map(targetClass::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all List<?> doesn't have any type information. You expect a List of SomeObject but your method just returns a List of any type.

To achieve your goal you should define your filter method as

```
private static  <T extends SomeInterface> List<T> filterGenericList(List<T> objects, String flag)
```

In this way you guarantee that the returned list is of the same type like the input list